# Cannot use text in option value with keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want be able to capture to name=`formdesc` an option value that is text and not numbers, but I need numbers to calculate price point below. Is there a way to change it, so that it calculates properly (below JS) and capture option values as text only instead numbers (HTML)?

Sample of what I need:

```
    <select id="apparelType" name="formdesc">
    <option selected="selected" value="na">Select</option>
    <option value="tshirt">T-Shirt</option>
```

BUT Breakes my JS!

HTML: (what I have now)

```
<select id="apparelType" name="formdesc">
    <option selected="selected" value="na">Select</option>
    <option value="0">T-Shirt</option>
    <option value="1">Shorts</option>
    <option value="2">Hat</option>
    <option value="3">Bag</option>
</select>
<input id="numb" type="number" name="formterm">
<id="tot"><Total: $0.00&nbsp;>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
// 
$(document).ready(function(){
                          $('#numb').keyup(function(){
                                                        var appVal = new Array();
                                                        appVal[0] = 15; <--[tshirt]
                                                        appVal[1] = 20;
                                                        appVal[2] = 25;
                                                        appVal[3] = 30;
                                                        var cost = 0;
                                                        var fmapVal = $('#apparelType').val();
                                                        if (fmapVal == 'na')
                                                        { alert ('Please select an apparel type.');
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            cost = appVal[fmapVal];
                                                        };
                                                        //alert(cost);
                                                        var getNumb = $('#numb').val();
                                                        var baseTotal = cost * getNumb;
                                                        var getTax = baseTotal * .06;
                                                        var getTotal = baseTotal + getTax;
                                               $('#tot').html('Total: $' +  getTotal.toFixed(2));
                                                        $('#formbal').val(getTotal.toFixed(2));
                                         });
           });
  // ]]></script>
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code but your JS is incomplete.

Comment: Actually, I thought the default behavior was that it would be a text "0" and not a numeric 0. If you wanted numeric you have to convert, but you get text by default. I must have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I have included all of it now~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<select id="apparelType" name="apparelType">
    <option selected="selected" value="na">Select</option>
    <option value="0">T-Shirt</option>
    <option value="1">Shorts</option>
    <option value="2">Hat</option>
    <option value="3">Bag</option>
</select>

<label for="numb">Total: <span>$</span></label>
<input id="numb" type="number" name="formterm" value="0.00" >
<input id="pretaxTotal" type="hidden" value="0.00" >
<br>
<textarea id="formdesc" name="formdesc" rows="12" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#apparelType').change(function(){
    var apparelType = $('#apparelType');
    var fmapVal = apparelType.val();

    if (fmapVal == 'na') {
      alert('Please select an apparel type.');
    } else {
      var appVal = [ 15, 20, 25, 30 ];
      var description = apparelType.find('option:selected').text();
      var cost = appVal[fmapVal];

      var pretaxTotal = parseInt($('#pretaxTotal').val());
      var subtotal = pretaxTotal + cost;
      var updatedTotal = ( subtotal * 1.06 ).toFixed(2);

      $('#pretaxTotal').val(subtotal);
      $('#numb').val(updatedTotal);

      $('#formdesc').append(description + '\n');
    }
  });

  /* The following code is cosmetic. Makes dollar sign appear to be inside the input field */
  $('label > span').css('position','relative').css('left','20px').css('font-size','80%');
  $('input[type=number]').css('padding-left','15px');

</script>
```

Comment: This is a great idea.Thanks! I am just worried about all selection(s) being captured in "formdesc" as description of what was purchased, and also clearing copping cart.

Comment: how to make contents of "shoppingCart" an input field "formdesc" in the form??? This is very important, since I want to see what is selected. Thanks!

Comment: @DenisMujic I changed "shoppingCart" to a textarea input named "formdesc"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take option name then `val` is not what you need. Instead try this:

```
var optionName = $('#apparelType').find('option:selected').text();
```

Hope I understood you correctly (although it's hard).

Answer (score -1):

Could use a function with a case statement to get the cost from passed text strings:

```
function getVal(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'tshirt':
            cost = 15;
            break;
        case 'shorts':
            cost = 15;
            break;
        case 'hat':
            cost = 15;
            break;
        case 'bag':
            cost = 15;
            break;
        default:
            cost = 'Please select an option...';
            break;
    }
    return cost;
}
```

Then in your `if` statement use `cost = getVal(fmapVal);`.

Comment: Well, what if OP had hundreds of options for his select..??

Comment: Just to explain better: Below dropdown I have a field "numb" that is used to input numbers (quantity) to calculate total ammount. The dropdown is just selection of price point for that. I need to capture descriptions of these items as well. When I switvh to text the script stops calculating.

Comment: @A.V Notice the `Could use`. The question wasn't very clear as to the purpose/scope of the code. This could have been a simple solution based on the given information.